# Redux-Toolkit dispatch in useEffect hook results in an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, react-query

## Problem

I use `useMuation` from react-query to do post requests and get the user info from JSON and then try to store it to my redux store using useEffect according to the status given by react-query `useMutation` hook which is success. The problem rises in this status. all info is successfully stored in the redux store as you can see in the picture, but it causes infinite loop.

I tried to put an empty dependency array and even put `userData?.data?.data?.user?.name` and `userData?.data?.token` instead of `userData` but still the same.

### Error

[image]

### Store

[image]

### userSlice.ts

```ts
import { createSlice, configureStore, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type initialState = {
  user: string;
  dashboardIndex: number;
  theme: string;
  token: string;
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
};

const initialState: initialState = {
  user: "",
  dashboardIndex: 0,
  theme: "themeLight",
  token: "",
  isLoggedIn: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateUser(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    updateDashboardIndex(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      state.dashboardIndex = action.payload;
    },
    updateTheme(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.theme = action.payload;
    },
    updateToken(state, action: PayloadAction<string>) {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
    updateIsLoggedIn(state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
      state.isLoggedIn = action.payload;
    },
    reset: () => initialState,
  },
});

// ...
```

### Login.tsx

```ts
const LoginComponents = () => {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  const [loginObject, setLoginOject] = useState<loginObjectType>({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const {
    mutate,
    error,
    isError,
    isSuccess,
    data: userData,
  } = useQueryMutationInvalidateHooksPost("api/v1/users/login");
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

...

  // Signin process handler
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hi");
    if (isSuccess) {
      if (userData) {
        dispatch(usersActions.updateUser(userData?.data?.data?.user?.name));
        dispatch(usersActions.updateToken(userData?.data?.token));
        dispatch(usersActions.updateIsLoggedIn(!!userData?.data?.token));
        alert(
          `Succeeded in login. Welcome ${userData?.data?.data?.user?.name}!`
        );
        navigate("/home");
      }
    }

    if (isError) {
      if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
        alert(error?.response?.data?.message);
      }
    }
  }, [navigate, error, isSuccess, isError, userData, dispatch]);

 //  Button functions
  const submitHandler = async (
    event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!loginObject?.email || !loginObject?.password) {
      alert("Please input all required fields.");
    } else if (loginObject?.email && loginObject.password) {
      //  fetching data
      const temp = {
        ...loginObject,
      };
      mutate(temp);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use useEffect hook only for initializations and not as a handler.

To react on mutation success or error use the mutation as follows.

```
mutate(temp, {
  onSuccess: (data, variables, context) => {
    // add your success handling logic here
  },
  onError: (error, variables, context) => {
    // Add your error handling logic here
  },
  onSettled: (data, error, variables, context) => {
    // Code that must run, irrelevant of success or error, should be added here.
  },
})
```

This way you will get rid of your Signin process handler useeffect which will remove your looping logic.